# Problem with new version of react-native: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle

the new version of react-native (v 0.59) give me an error when trying to run that on a device or simulator:

C:\Pro\react-native jan\tictactoe>react-native run-android

info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
...............................................................................................................

Unzipping C:\Users\MAN.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv\gradle-4.10.2-all.zip to C:\Users\MAN.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv

Welcome to Gradle 4.10.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Incremental Java compilation by default
 - Periodic Gradle caches cleanup
 - Gradle Kotlin DSL 1.0-RC6
 - Nested included builds
 - SNAPSHOT plugin versions in the `plugins {}` block

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'tictactoe'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'.
  >   Connect to 127.0.0.1:50002 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'.
  >   Connect to 127.0.0.1:50002 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 55s
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug

what i have to do?

Comment: Can you add the contents of your project-level build.gradle?

Comment: i don't know whats your means!?
but if your mean is content of my build.gradle file, this is it:

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

,,,,

Comment: ,,,,  allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}